# Check If Request Duplicated In Short Interval of Time in PHP

Tags: php, search

I have some case based on php programs. I have implemented an search input form which is handle the searching needs. There has a controller handle the search request. Once i realize that the action of request wether it POST or GET may cause a hole that allowing people repeat the request in short interval of time. What i'am thinking is about to check the last request and compare to the current request. If the interval matched with the forbidden time range (said that it was about 0-500ms), the controller won't do searching until the request passed the time range.

I have thinking to save the request on the table and key is on the requestor real_IP. Then  compare it with the new request (CMIIW).

Is there any good approach to get this properly?

Comment: What is the problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Jon there is no specific problem in it. just limiting the request that access search feature of the web programs. when i ask this i'am remember about the works of brute force or kind web stress. So i would like to make it secure so the server.

Answer (score 2):

Using IP to limit the number of searches will cause any institute (eg: schools) to be unable to use your service/website/search. Using a session limits the use to the browser session; closing the browser will remove the session variable and thus allows new users to use your application.

A better method would be to set the last search time (as you propose) in a session variable and check on that variable to be inexistant or later than 500ms ago to fulfill the search request.

For a session variable to be set you can use `$_SESSION['lastsearchtime']` after the session is loaded `session_start()`. Please be aware that session_start can trigger errors when it has already been called.

Answer (score 2):

This solution uses $_SESSION instead:

```
session_start();

$now = microtime(true); 
$interval = $now - 2;

if( 
  isset( $_SESSION['last_request'] ) 
  && ($_SESSION['last_request'] >= $interval) 
){   
  exit('timeout'); 
}

$_SESSION['last_request'] = $now;

//do query
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several options here:

1. Implement a one time token (in wordpress, it is called [nonce](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces)). and on every request, you check it. If the token already used and it is used again (by subsequent request), refuse that request).
2. Implement last request time in session variable and check the later request if still within time window, reject that request. For this, you can check **Max Gherkins**'s answer.